# Linux Wildcard (*) is implemented on User Space or Kernel Space?

Tags: linux, wildcard

I've researched so far that Wildcards in Linux were a binary located in /etc/glob, or in C functions called glob(). Nowadays it's native in any Unix-based system, but, it's confusing to understand where it runs, when we type something like:

```
mv * folder
ls *
```

**Is it running in user space or kernel space?**

This is the [context](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Kernel space used when Kernel is executing on the behalf of the user program i.e.
> System Call? Or is it the address space for all the Kernel threads (for example
> scheduler)?
>
> > Yes and yes.

They will I presume use glob(3), a system call, to accomplish this. System calls take place in kernel space. Also glob(3) will make other system calls such as opendir(), also running in kernel space.

Answer (score 3):

This is done at the shell level in the example you give, e.g. bash, tcsh, etc. They will I presume use glob(3), a C library function, to accomplish this. This is strictly user-space.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such syscall *glob*. The wildcard feature in bash is provided by the glob() function, which runs in the *user space*. Credits for @Vercingatorix

To see a list of syscalls, run `man syscalls`.

This new reply is for calling out that the accepted answer is wrong and can mislead readers.